# Trigger Angular async FormGroup validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

**Background**

Asynchronous validation on a FormGroup is only executed when all synchronous validation for that group and all of its children are valid.

**Issue**

I want to execute a asyncValidator on a FormGroup before all children are valid.

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  country: [ null, [ Validators.required ] ],
  postalCode: [ null ],
  unrelatedField1: [ null ],
  unrelatedField2: [ Validators.min(123) ]
}, {
  validators: [ postalCodeFormat ],
  asyncValidators: [ postalCodeExists ]
})
```

My custom postalCodeExists validator needs the country and postalCode field. It doesn't care about the validity of 'unrelatedField2'.

Is there any way I can trigger the async validation of a FormGroup manually?

**My first idea**

As far as I know this is not possible.

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(...etc),
  distinctUntilChanges(...etc)
).subscribe(() => {
  if (this.myForm.get('country').valid && this.myForm.get('postalCode').valid) {
    this.myForm.executeAsyncValidationPlease();
  }
});
```

**My second idea**

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  countryAndPostalCodeGroup: new FormGroup({
    country: [ null, [ Validators.required ] ],
    postalCode: [ null ],
  }, {
    validators: [ postalCodeFormat ],
    asyncValidators: [ postalCodeExists ]
  }),

  unrelatedField1: [ null ],
  unrelatedField2: [ Validators.min(123) ]
})
```

It will work. But I don't like it. I strongly prefer to have one data structure for myForm, all APIs and data stores. Doing `this.myForm.setValue(dataFromApi)` or the opposite `.getValue()` variant is really helpful.